# не знаю как изучить javascript

Tags: javascript

Вот не знаю как изучить javascript. Хочу практиковаться, но не хватает знаний. А я не знаю откуда брать знания

Answer (score -1):

Вот есть [хороший онлайн учебник](http://www.wisdomweb.ru/JS/javascript-first.php), а дальше нужно браться за решение простых задач и переходить к более сложным, на практике так сказать руку набить.